# Start section numbering after contents, figures and tables lists

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, numbering

I'm using the article class for a PhD thesis.

I want the section numbering to start after my lists at the beginning of the document, including the table of contents itself (generated in the usual way).

The document is generated with the following:

```
\begin{document}

%%% TITLE PAGE
\maketitle
\pagenumbering{arabic}


\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\newpage

%%% SECTIONS
\input{src/glossary}
\input{src/symbols}
\input{src/aims}
\input{src/litreview}
\input{src/methodology}
\input{src/results}
\input{src/outlook}
\input{src/bibliography}



\end{document}
```

I want chapter 1 to start with src/aims, with what comes before them unnumbered.

I need some way of excluding `\listoffigures`, `\listoftables` and `\tableofcontents` from the numbering, but as these are commands rather than sections, how can this be accomplished?

`\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` are written about as potential solutions, though they don't work in the article class. (and with the book class caused further problems). 
Is there a better way?

This is the preamble I've been using

```
\documentclass[12pt,article,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{chemfig}         
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}                 
\usepackage[hyperpageref]{backref}  
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=false}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{morefloats}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Matthew Worsdale}
\lhead{\rightmark}

\newcommand*{\vimage}[1]{\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics{#1}}}}
\newcommand*{\vpointer}{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{2}{\Huge\pointer}}}}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage{color}

\title{Ab-Initio Investigation into catalyst supports for Polymer Electrolyte     Fuel Cells\\[1cm]\textbf{PhD Thesis}}

\author{Matthew Worsdale
\url{mw2a11@soton.ac.uk}
\thanks{PhD student-Engineering Materials Research Group, University of     Southampton, SO17 1BJ, UK} 
}

\date{December 2014}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
\section{\contentsname}%
\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}%
    {\MakeUppercase\contentsname}%
\@starttoc{toc}%
}
\renewcommand\listoftables{%
\section{\listtablename}%
\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listtablename}%
    {\MakeUppercase\listtablename}%
\@starttoc{lot}%
}
\renewcommand\listoffigures{%
\section{\listfigurename}%
\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
    {\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
\@starttoc{lof}%
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: article is not made to write a PhD thesis but short text as an article. What is the problem when you use the book class?

Comment: As @Romain points out, article isn't suited. It doesn't have chapters either. By the way, those auto-generated lists should be unnumbered by default. Please show us your preamble as well. Better even, a compilable example.

Comment: I added my preamble. The main problem using the book class was that the numbering went up a level; so the contents was 0.1, and everything following from that. And the subsections disappeared, which I think is a consequence of the same change.

Comment: @JSmoov: Sorry, this is a quite messy setup and contradicting -- the lists should be numbered, the `src/glossary` shouldn't be numbered, starting from `src/aims` it should be numbered again

Comment: Out of interest, where did you get the template from?

Answer (score 2):

This is a proposition:

`\usepackage{tocbibind}` and using `\tocchapter` as the command, making numbered chapters for all `toc` like entries. If `article` is still to be used, replace `\tocchapter` with `\tocsection`

Some other issues: `hyperref` is one package, that should come last, but here before `glossaries`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,article,a4paper]{book}


\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{chemfig}         
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}                 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{morefloats}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}


\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage[hyperpageref]{backref}  
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=false}

\usepackage{glossaries}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Matthew Worsdale}
\lhead{\rightmark}

\newcommand*{\vimage}[1]{\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics{#1}}}}
\newcommand*{\vpointer}{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{2}{\Huge\pointer}}}}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage{color}

\title{Ab-Initio Investigation into catalyst supports for Polymer Electrolyte     Fuel Cells\\[1cm]\textbf{PhD Thesis}}

\author{Matthew Worsdale
\url{mw2a11@soton.ac.uk}
\thanks{PhD student-Engineering Materials Research Group, University of     Southampton, SO17 1BJ, UK} 
}

\date{December 2014}
\thispagestyle{empty}




\tochapter


\begin{document}

%%% TITLE PAGE
\maketitle
\pagenumbering{arabic}


\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\newpage


\chapter*{Glossary}
% etc
%%% SECTIONS
%\input{src/glossary}
%\input{src/symbols}

\chapter{Foo}

%\input{src/aims}
%\input{src/litreview}
%\input{src/methodology}
%\input{src/results}
%\input{src/outlook}
%\input{src/bibliography}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Christian, that is helpful. However, my primary aim is to stop the Contents, List of Figures and List of Tables from having a section number when they appear in the table of contents, so that it is easier for someone reading my thesis to remember what number corresponds to the motivation, results, conclusion sections etc

Comment: @JSmoov: You're contradiction your requests. In your example, you use `\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{...\section{...}}` this is numbered. The `toc` etc. aren't numbered by default. Why did you use that ill-behaved code then?

Comment: It was my mistake, and sorted now